# Area of hyperbolic triangle in terms of Lengths of its sides

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Let a, b and c denote the cosh of the lengths of the
sides of an hyperbolic triangle and A, B, and C its angles.

Its area is well knwon to be S = pi - A - B - C .

What is S in terms of a, b, c ?

In J. Smorodinskij, Fortschritte der Physik, 18 (1965) 157 -- 173

I find (without reference or proof)

cos(S/2) = (1 + a + b + c) / (4 (a' b' c')^2)

where a' is the cosh of half the lenght of the side a.

My cumbersum calculations yield

cos(S/2) = (1 + a + b + c) / (4 (a' b' c'))

Where do I find a simple proof of this simple formula?

Answer (score 3):

One proof is sketched here: http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/wws/cabripages/hyperbolic/harea2.html
A more brute force way of expressing area through side lengths is to use the [hyperbolic law of cosines.](http://math2.uncc.edu/~ghetyei/courses/old/S14.6118/hypsingen.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Your version of the formula is correct. The proof can be found, for example, on pp. 102-103 in http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0462 (The Hyperbolic Theory of Special Relativity, by J.F. Barrett).